# Multiple if/else conditions to check last characters in a list of strings

Tags: python

I have this list

```
num_list=["mille", "duemila", "tremila", "quattromila", "cinquemila", "seimila", "settemila", "ottomila", "novemila", "diecimila", "milione", "miliardo", "milioni",'miliardi','mila']
```

I would like to build the following list

```
output=['millesimo', 'duemillesimo','tremillesimo','quattromillesimo','cinquemillesimo','seimillesimo','settemillesimo', 'ottomillesimo', 'novemillesimo', 'diecimillesimo', 'milionesimo', 'miliardesimo', 'milionesimo','miliardesimo']
```

This should be built by following the conditions below, after removing the last character from each string:

- if the word is '`mila`' do nothing;
- if the word ends with '`l`' then add '`lesimo`';
- else (if the last two characters of the string, after removing the last character, are '`ll`' or  the string is "`milion`", "`miliard`"), then add '`esimo`';

I started to do as follows:

```
numeri_card_esimo = [x[:-1] + 'lesimo' if x[:-2] == 'll' else x[:-1] + 'esimo' for x in numeri_card_esimo]
```

and the output is not so close to that one I would like:

```
['millesimo',
 'duemilesimo', # it should be duemillesimo
 'tremilesimo', # same as above
 'quattromilesimo', # same as above
 'cinquemilesimo', # same as above
 'seimilesimo', # same as above
 'settemilesimo', # same as above
 'ottomilesimo', # same as above
 'novemilesimo', # same as above
 'diecimilesimo', # same as above
 'milionesimo',
 'miliardesimo',
 'milionesimo',
 'milesimo'] # it should be excluded
```

but it does not work because of wrong use of `if/else` conditions. How should I write these conditions?

Comment: It would help if you mentioned how exactly it doesn't work. Like, is there an error? Is the output not what you were expecting? See [mre] for reference.

Comment: You have two very obvious syntax errors in three places. Is that what you're asking about? If not, LMK when you fix them and I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: Sorry wjandrea but I disagree with you. I added data that I am using, expected output and code that contains 'obvious syntax errors' that I know to be there but I do not how to fix them (otherwise I think I would not have asked the question). I think it is in the wrong use of if/else. I posted something that should be reproduced (data), the code that should be fixed, and expected output. Please let me know if you need any things but I think this is a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: OK, I've undone the downvote. Please post the error you're getting. The reason I'm confused is that for a syntax error, data is irrelevant. The error gets raised before any expressions or variables are evaluated. So where you talk about the algorithm before actually introducing the problem, and the problem turns out to be basically some typos, that made me think you hadn't put in any effort to actually fixing the problem.

Comment: Anyway, so, you've fixed one syntax error now, which is good. The other is at `x[:-1] = 'e'` and `x[:-1]='o'`. That equals `=` is supposed to be a double-equals `==`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the spot. I am reviewing the code as I think I am doing some confusion with the suffix. I got an invalid syntax error, but the problem is still in the suffix. I need to check the values in the expected output and the original sentence as I am confusing myself

Comment: I think this one is close but it would benefit from getting broken down into a "classic" if-else format and reconstructed back to ternary.

Comment: Welcome! Now that you've gotten the syntax fixed, please post the output you're currently getting.

Comment: I updated the question with the output that I am getting

Comment: BTW keep in mind that SO is not really built for fixing broken code per se, but for asking questions about code. Ideally you would have asked a question about the syntax, then another question about the algorithm/implementation. But don't worry about it now.

Comment: no wjandrea, I asked for the expected output. The problem with signs was only here, not in my original code in my notebook. I have never talked about syntax error in the post, but only in the comment when I tried to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the logic you are trying to apply is a bit long to be used in a list comprehension. It is better to move it into a function for the sake of readability.

```
def convert(num):
    num = num[:-1]
    if num[-2:]=='ll' or num=='milion' or num=='miliard':
        num = num + 'esimo'
    elif word[-1]=='l':
        num = num + 'lesimo'
    return num

num_list=["mille", "duemila", "tremila", "quattromila", "cinquemila", "seimila", "settemila", "ottomila", "novemila", "diecimila", "milione", "miliardo", "milioni",'miliardi','mila']

# Remove mila occurrences
num_list = [num for num in num_list if num!='mila']
output = [convert(num) for num in num_list]
print(output)
```